# tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer - TypeError: 'Not JSON Serializable:'

Tags: json, tensorflow, serialization, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(). I did everything according to the docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/MultiOptimizer) yet I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/model_80/dense_3/Tensordot/MatMul/MatMul:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>)

Below is a minimal, working example that reproduces the error, just copy and paste it. The error occurs when the first epoch is finished and the callback trys to save the model.

```
##############################################################################

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow.keras.layers as l
import tensorflow_addons.layers as la
import tensorflow.keras as ke
import numpy as np

##############################################################################

def build_model_1():

    model_input = l.Input(shape=(32,1))

    x = l.Dense(1)(model_input)

    model = ke.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x)

##########  
    
    optimizers = [tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()]
    
    optimizers_and_layers = [(optimizers[0], model.layers[:5]), (optimizers[1], model.layers[5:])]
    
    optimizer = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(optimizers_and_layers)
    
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics='mse')

    test = tf.keras.optimizers.serialize(optimizer)

    return model

##############################################################################

input_data =  np.arange( 0, 10000, 1).reshape(10000,1)
target_data = np.arange(-10000, 0, 1).reshape(10000,1)

model = build_model_1()

model_checkpoint = ke.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5',
                                                monitor='val_mse',
                                                mode='min',
                                                save_best_only=True,
                                                verbose=1)

training_history = model.fit(x = input_data,
                             y = target_data,
                             validation_split = 0.2,
                             epochs = 5,
                             verbose = 1,
                             callbacks = [model_checkpoint])
    
##############################################################################
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving a **complete** Keras model (with its own structure in the `.h5` file) the `tf.keras.Model` object is **completely** serialized as a JSON: this means that every property of the model should be JSON serializable.

NOTE: `tf.Tensor` are NOT JSON serializable.

When using this multi optimizer from `tfa` you're adding properties to the model that the JSON serializer will try (and fail) to serialize.

In particular there's this attribute `gv` that I think it comes from the custom optimizer used.

```
'gv': [(<tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/model/dense/Tensordot/MatMul/MatMul:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.55191684]], dtype=float32)>), (<tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/model/dense/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.23444518], dtype=float32)>)]},
```

All this `tf.Tensor` are not JSON serializable, that's why it fails.

The only option is to do not save the model **completely** (with all its attributes, which should be defined as Keras layers, but in this case is not possible) but saving only the model parameters.

In short, if you add the `save_weights_only=True` to the callback your training (and checkpoint of the weights) will work fine.

```py
model_checkpoint = ke.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    "best_model.h5",
    monitor="val_mse",
    mode="min",
    save_best_only=True,
    verbose=1,
    save_weights_only=True,
)
```

Comment: This works. Thank you for your quick reply and the detailed explanation :)